# Area of equilateral triangle inscribed in right triangle

Tags: geometry

An Isosceles right triangle  $ABC$  , $AB=BC= 4 cm$

Point $p$ is a midpoint of $BC$ , points $q$, $s$  lies on $AC$,$AB$ respectively  , such that the triangle $pqs$ is  an equilateral triangle ;

what is the area of triangle $pqs$

[image]

Comment: @Arnaldo  i have tried using analytic geometry  to find equations  and intersection points but i stuck,  angle   ∠B=90

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotate $\Delta Bps$ clockwise $60^\circ$ about $p$ as shown, to form $\Delta B'pq$.

Using $\Delta B'Cp$, find that $B'C=2\sqrt3~\mathrm{cm}$.

Using Sine Law on $\Delta B'Cq$, find that $\dfrac{B'q}{\sin 15^\circ}=\dfrac{B'C}{\sin 105^\circ}$, so $B'q=(4\sqrt3-6)~\mathrm{cm}$.

Use Pythagoras' theorem on $\Delta B'pq$ to find that $pq=2\sqrt{22-12\sqrt3}~\mathrm{cm}$.

Therefore the area is $\dfrac12a^2\sin60^\circ=(22\sqrt3-36)~\mathrm{cm}^2$.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant  solution  , i have question;  how did you get  angle $qpB'$=$15$

Comment: I meant $\angle B'Cq=15^\circ$, as we are considering $\Delta B'Cq$

Comment: realy i didn't  get that ; can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Using Sine Law on $\Delta B'Cq$: $\dfrac{B'q}{\sin\angle B'CQ} = \dfrac{B'C}{\sin\angle B'qC}$

Comment: you are Brilliant  , I got that , thank you

Comment: How do you know that rotating the triangle $pBs$ by $60^\circ$ about $p$ will cause $s$ to land on the hypotenuse?

Comment: @HocNgo $\Delta pqs$ is equilateral and the angle of rotation to cause $s$ to land on the hypotenuse is $\angle spq = 60^\circ$.

Comment: Thanks. I can see now that you can compute $B'C$ from the triangle $B'pC$, from which you can compute $B'q$. That's very elegant.

Comment: @DHMO  I was initially not convinced because if point $s$ were arbitrary on edge $AB$, rotating the triangle $pBs$ by $60^\circ$ about $p$ would not land $s$ on $AC$.  It's now easier to understand if we show how to construct the equilateral triangle first and prove it later. First, rotate the triangle $pBA$ by  $60^\circ$ about $p$. The new edge $B'A'$ will intersect the edge $AC$ at $q$.  Next, draw an arc of radius 2 centered at $p$; let the intersection between the arc and edge $AB$ be $s$. Finally, proceed to prove that $pqs$ is the equilateral triangle as you did.

Comment: @HocNgo you're over-complicating everything. I simply glued two triangles together, which is guaranteed by the fact that pqs is equilateral. Then, I found the angles by letting one of the components to be $\theta$ then finding that the other components are $120^\circ-\theta$ (which combines with $\theta$ to form the $120^\circ$ I marked), $90^\circ-\theta$ and $15^\circ+\theta$ (which form $115^\circ$). I only said to rotate "by $60^\circ$" for extra rigor.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, let's define:

$$ \begin{align}
\mbox{Hypotenuse AC}:\; y &= -x +4 \\
p &= (2,0) \\
q &= (x, y=-x+4) \\
s & = (0,h)
\end{align}$$

The three sides are equal, hence:

$$ \begin{align}
\mbox{sp = pq} \Rightarrow 
4+h^2 &= (x-2)^2 + (x-4)^2 \quad (1)\\
\mbox{sp = sq} \Rightarrow 
4+h^2 &= x^2 + (h+x-4)^2, \quad(2) \\
\mbox{pq = sq} \Rightarrow 
(x-2)^2 + (x-4)^2 &=  x^2 + (h+x-4)^2. \quad(3)\\
\end{align}$$

There are 3 equations with only 2 variables $x$ and $h$ but only two equations are needed to solve for the variables. Let's say we solve $(2)$ and $(3)$ for $x$ and $h$. Then we plug the solution in to $(1)$ and if $(1)$ is not satisfied, then the problem has no solution.

From $(3)$:

$$ x = \frac{4 + 8h -h^2}{4 + 2h}. \quad(4) $$

Plugging $(4)$ into $(2)$ will result in an equation in $h$ alone. This equation can be solved numerically. Once $h$ is obtained, $x$ will be found by $(4)$.

The next step is to plug the results for $x$ and $h$ into $(1)$. If the equality fails, the problem has no solution.

If the problem has a solution, then the area of the triangle $spq$ is given by

$$ A = \frac{\sqrt3}{4}(sp)^2 =  \frac{\sqrt3}{4}(4+h^2). $$